# Reading .dcm files from a nested directory

Tags: python, directory, pydicom

This is the form of my nested directory:

```
/data/patient_level/study_level/series_level/
```

For each **patient_level** folder, I need to read the "**.dcm**" files from the corresponding "**series_level**" folder.

How can I access the ".dcm" file in the "series_level" folders?

I need 3 features from a DICOM object.

This is my source code:

```
import dicom
record = dicom.read_file("/data/patient_level/study_level/series_level/000001.dcm")
doc = {"PatientID": record.PatientID, "Manufacturer": record.Manufacturer, "SeriesTime": record.SeriesTime}
```

Then, I will insert this doc to a Mongo DB.

Any suggestions is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: When you say "each patient_level folder", what does that mean exactly? Is there any way you could run something like [`tree`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/) to show the structure of all the directories (starting from data)?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I meant in "data", there are different sub-folders and each of them correspond to a "patient study". In "patient_study" folder, there are different subfolders (not one) and each of them corresponds to one series.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Basically, what I was trying to explain is that there are multiple patient information, each with multiple study information, each with multiple series information. I am trying to think of a way that can recursively capture all .dcm files which are in all the series level subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear the problem you are trying to solve, but if all you want is to get a list of all `.dcm` files from that the `data` directory, you can use [`pathlib.Path()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path):

```py
from pathlib import Path

data = Path('/data')
list(data.rglob('*.dcm'))
```

To split a file in its components, you can use something like this:

```py
dcm_file = '/patient_level/study_level/series_level/000001.dcm'
_, patient_level, study_level, series_level, filename = dcm_file.split('/')
```

Which would give you `patient_level`, `study_level`, `series_level`, and `filename` from `dcm_file`.

But it would be better to stick with `Path()` and its methods, like this:

```py
dcm_file = Path('/patient_level/study_level/series_level/000001.dcm')
dcm_file.parts
```

Which would give you something like this:

```py
('/', 'patient_level', 'study_level', 'series_level', '000001.dcm')
```

Those are just starting points anyway.